# What's a great way to have this operate as a class

Tags: php

I understand how classes are useful, but don't know what's the proper way to create ones that have prepared statements. I've started making a class and I want a method called isOnline that returns if the url is online.

```
// This is the code I'm trying to make a class.

global $db;
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT url FROM urls WHERE rel=? ORDER BY url");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION['admin_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
?>
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
  {

    $url = $row['url'];

    $site = strtolower($url);

      // check if is online

       $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
            CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://'.$site ) );
        $headers = explode( "\n", curl_exec( $curl ) );

        $statushttp = $headers[0];

        if(!$statushttp == 0){

        }else{

              $curl = curl_init();
              curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
                  CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
                  CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://'.$site ) );
              $headers = explode( "\n", curl_exec( $curl ) );

              $statushttp = $headers[0];

        }


        echo "$url with $statushttp <br>";

        // email person here.



  }
$stmt->free_result();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing to determine if a site is online or not but as far as creating a class to handle this.  You should use something like this.  If you can explain what you are doing to determine if a site is up or not I can update the class.

```
class SomeClassNameHere{

    //this is the constructor of the class.  This is ran when you create it
    public SomeClassNameHere(){

    }

    //this is a public function that you can call 
    public function isOnline(){
        //this is the first step to breaking up this into smaller peaces
        //I moved your section of code that gets the urls from the database
        //into a function that returns the rows from the database below.
        $rows = getUrls();
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
            $site = strtolower($row['url']);
        }
        // check if is online
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://'.$site ) );
        $headers = explode( "\n", curl_exec( $curl ) );
        $statushttp = $headers[0];

        if(!$statushttp == 0){

        }else{

          $curl = curl_init();
          curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
              CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
              CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_URL => 'http://'.$site ) );
          $headers = explode( "\n", curl_exec( $curl ) );

          $statushttp = $headers[0];

        }
        //I wouldn't echo out the results here, 
        //I would have this function return a true or false and do the display
        //somewhere else

        //like this
        if(statushttp == whateverIsTrue){   //remember to edit this
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    //this has the possibility to return more than one row.  You will need to
    //change your function to handle this.
    public function getUrls(){
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT url FROM urls WHERE rel=? ORDER BY url");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION['admin_id']);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->get_result();
    }
}
```

To call this class you would want to do something like this.

```
//this is creating an instance of the class
$foo= new SomeClassNameHere();
//this will call the isOnline function of that class and return true or false
$siteOnline = $foo->isOnline();
if($siteOnline){
    echo "Yeah!";
}else{
    echo "Sad:-(";
}
```

Comment: I'm connecting to a db of url's for a specific user then using curl to get the header response.

Comment: ok, I've update the answer to help point you in a better direction.  The point of the class is to break things apart to make classes/object/models/services.  Thinking of things like objects instead of just code.

Comment: I've tested this, but I'm not getting any errors or it returning anything. I did this $u = new Scanner(21);

$u->getURLS();

echo $u->isOnline();

Comment: @DrewPeer I've updated the answer to show how to call the class and function.  I've also added notes in the original function of what you need to change for the class to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the responses and edits - Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getUrls() is what I get. I edit the getUrls() method.